# template to specialize a function's parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function `int f (int x, int y)` which needs to call itself plenty of times, with one of its parameters fixed, as in

```
int f(int x, int y) { 
      ...
      int i = f(z,y);
      ...
}
```

Is there any way of defining via a template a function `int g (int x)` such that `g(z) := f(z,y)` so that the above call would have been `int i = g(z)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define that without any templating,

```
auto f( int x, int y )
    -> int
{
    auto g = [=]( int z ) -> int { return f( z, y ); };
    // ...
    int i = g( z );
}
```

You can omit the `-> int` result type specification for `g` if you want.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.