# runtime specialization of overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

This is a variant of  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39583355/4283108). I have an overloaded function that takes parameters of different types and returns different types:

```
struct mystruct {
  auto f (int x, int y) -> int;
  auto f (std::string x, int y) -> float;
};
```

The function `f` needs to call itself with one of its parameters specialized a number of times. 
I'd like to define a function that specializes the parameter `y`, that is I'd want `g(z) = f(z,y)`. The return type of `g` and the type of its unique parameter `z` variable, but the implementation is the same in both cases.

The best implementation I could find of this situation is overloading the lambda function:

```
template <class F1, class F2>
struct overload_set : F1, F2
{
  overload_set(F1 f1, F2 f2) : F1(f1), F2(f2) {}

  using F1::operator();
  using F2::operator();
};
template <class F1, class F2>
overload_set<F1, F2> overload(F1 f1, F2 f2) {
  return overload_set<F1, F2>(f1, f2);
};

struct mystruct { 
  auto f( std::string x, int y) -> float {
  return y+9.3;
  }
  auto f( int x, int y) -> int
  {
    auto g = overload (
      [=]( int z ) -> int {return f(z,y);},
      [=]( std::string z) -> float { return f(z,y); }
    );
  if ( x == 0 ) {
    std::cout << g("this string") << "\n";
    return 0;
  }
  if ( x == 1 ) return y;
  return 7;
  }
};
int main () {
  mystruct h;
  std::cout << h.f(1,4) << "\n";
  std::cout << h.f(0,2) << "\n";
}
```

which works as expected but seems overkill. It seems that a simple preprocessor macro of the form

```
#define k(z) f(z,y)
```

would also work. Is there a good way of achieving this?

Comment: are you restricted to c++11? why not just simply use `auto g(auto z) -> decltype(f(z, y))`?

Comment: I tried that and didn't work, if you post code that works with that approach as an answer I'll accept it and thank you.

Comment: Where does `y` come from in the new case?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are attempting to do but here is a working (c++14) example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct mystruct {
  static auto f (int x, int y) -> int {
     std::cout << "f(" << x << "," << y << ")" << std::endl;
     auto g = [=](auto z) -> decltype(mystruct::f(z, y)) {
       return mystruct::f(z, y);
     };
     if (x < 1)
        g("end");
     else
        g(x - 1);
  }
  static auto f (std::string x, int y) -> float {
     std::cout << "f(\"" << x << "\"," << y << ")" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
   mystruct::f(10, 1);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> f(10,1)
> f(9,1)
> f(8,1)
> f(7,1)
> f(6,1)
> f(5,1)
> f(4,1)
> f(3,1)
> f(2,1)
> f(1,1)
> f(0,1)
> f("end",1)
> ```

Comment: Oh sorry, I posted in my original question but not in this one, `g` is to be called within `f` as in my example. I'll edit the question

Comment: So it's kind of recursion(?) I don't think that this changes anything in the logic... Though I'm not sure when you would like to invoke one of the overloading and when another... Is it dependent of runtime parameter value?

Comment: yes it is, the function `g` should be a wrapper to just calling f with a bunch of parameters being the same and just changing one parameters. In my example in the question this works, but it's a bit involved. I do not know how to make your example work in this way

Comment: I have edited the answer. I think first thing you need to do is to define boundary conditions i.e. when you want to recursion to stop...

Comment: This works only for static f, but its simpler than my overloading lambdas and I can implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

This produces the same answer, and I think is a little clearer:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct mystruct
{
    auto f( std::string x, int y) -> float {
        return y+9.3;
    }

    auto f( int x, int y) -> int
    {
        switch(x)
        {
            case 0: {
                auto g = [=](auto...args) { return f(args..., y); };
                std::cout << g("this string") << "\n";
                return 0;
            } break;

            case 1: {
                return y;
            } break;

            default:
                return 7;
        }
    }
};
int main () {
    mystruct h;
    std::cout << h.f(1,4) << "\n";
    std::cout << h.f(0,2) << "\n";
}
```

Maybe in reality there are more switch cases, and `g` needs to be hoisted above the `switch` statement?